# Extreme Values in Bayesian Regression Model

Tags: regression, bayesian, model, negative-binomial-distribution

I fitted a hurdle negative binomial model using a fully parametric Bayesian regression model. This was done in R with the `brms` package. The outcome was count data. I am interested in a measure of "extreme values", something like the probability of observing a more extreme value than the observed one under the posterior distribution. The reason behind this is I want a probabilistic analogue to the $p$-value of a frequentist model and to assess if they reach similar conclusions.

Any guidance would be appreciated, I am quite inexperienced with fitting those models and interpreting them.

Comment: Have you just considered using a Bayes factor instead?

Comment: I was under the impression that Bayes factor can be used to either compare models or for a global comparison in general, rather than obtaining a measure of how extreme an observation is under the model fitted. Please explain how you would use a Bayes factor. As I said, I am a beginner in using Bayesian models. It might be worth mentioning that I am using a subset of the data for the fit and then hope to use the predicted values for the whole data set to obtain a list of extreme observations.

Comment: I'm trying to grasp your purpose here. So you're not doing tests (of parameters). You want to measure how extreme an *observation* is. AFAIK Bayesian/frequentist modeling doesn't allow that kind of comparison: in Bayesian data the observation is fixed, so it doesn't have a probability measure. In frequentist modeling the parameters are fixed, so you can assign a probability to an observation's cumulative value.

Comment: My purpose is rather simple... I am modelling a process that results in counts and I know that there is a small sub-population which does not arise from the process modelled. Therefore I am trying to extract potential observations that are least explained by the model. No, they are not separable in a residuals plot and hence why I am trying to extract the most extreme outliers with some probability or quantify how well they are explained by the model fitted.

Comment: What you describe is a mixture model. The Bayesian approach is'nt flagging and parametrizing extreme observations. Update the probability model to be a mixture process and estimate the posterior $p_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ using naive Bayes or another process. You can then create a rule for classifying data as belonging to one cluster vs. another.